# Getting different chi square values than sklearn function

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection

I have a dataset which looks like this-

[image]

I am trying to use chi2 as a feature selction algorithm on it.Here is the code

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('small_dataset.csv')
print(dataset.shape)


X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:106].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,0].values


print(sklearn.feature_selection.chi2(X, y))
```

I tried to validate the answers from sklearn and the formula which is

[image]

[image]

so I took the first feature and computed the A B C D which are 0 19 73 73 and N is 146.So the X2 value coming is 21 but in sklearn its coming 579.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did I answer it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using Scipy's [chi2_contingency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html). It turns out that the Scipy function uses by default `correction=True`, and the statistic you showed doesn't use the correction. Perhaps sklearn's `chi2` uses the correction as well, and that's the reason you don't get the same results. I suggest trying Scipy's with both correction set to true and false to see if it matches the two results.

Comment: the problem with scipy is it doesnt accept as input the feature vector table I have as a input....thats why I used the skearn